# bxslider: showing half an image outside of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

**tl;dr version**: want to position half an image outside of the bxslider div however overflow:hidden causes every slide of the carousel to show up.

Code I'm using: http://www.dtcontentguy.com/bxslider/

Screenshots: http://screencast.com/t/bTTvC4VPEQ

**Long version:**

So configuring bxslider for a carousel to use on my site.

How it should look like (in photoshop) (see screenshot 1)

My main concern is the circular png I'm using. To match the style, I want to position the top half of it outside the div. I position it then it looks like this, all cut off (screenshot 2)

That's because by default there is a overflow:hidden to hide the other portions of the carousel. If I turn off the overflow:hidden, the image looks fine but of course the other items show (screenshot 3)

How do I get the image to conform with the carousel but get around the overflow:hidden?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to increase the height of the container and push the content down like so:

```
/* Increase container height, align background to bottom */
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    height: 456px!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom center;
}
/* Push slider arrows down */
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.bxslider {
    margin: 0;
}
/* Push slider content down */
.bxslider li {
    padding-top: 184px;
}
/* Position image at top center */
.bxslider li img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -91px;
}
```